How can I highlight variables with an any type in TypeScript code in VS Code?
Sometimes a TypeScript variable can get an unsafe any type without your explicitly writing the word any:

To increase the visibility of these any-typed variables, I'd like to highlight them in red in VS Code. Is it possible to configure my theme to do this? If not, is there an extension I could install to do this?

Lint it? https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-restricted-types

@jonrsharpe that wouldn't help here since that any is inherent to lib.d.ts rather than an explicit annotation. OP might want to checkout this library which doesn't answer the question but does solve the issue...

My problem isn't specific to JSON.parse, that's just an easy example. I'm aware of the various typescript-eslint rules around any types, but I'm curious to see if syntax highlighting could be a more pleasant way to see surprising anys.
